Error: Missing or invalid parameters. Double check you have provided the correct parameters. Even with correct type casting
I am using latest Next.js and written a function to write to a contract. But i when i call the function it is returnin this error message 'Error: Missing or invalid parameters. Double check you have provided the correct parameters.'. I have tried every conversion to fix this issue but i cannot make it work. How can i fix this issue ?
Abi:
{
          "inputs": [
            {
              "internalType": "uint256",
              "name": "tokenId",
              "type": "uint256"
            }
          ],
          "name": "mintNFT",
          "outputs": [],
          "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
          "type": "function"
        }

Function in question:
async function submitContract(tokenId:any) {
    let str = Number(tokenId).toString()
    console.log(str)
    writeMint({
      address: VehicleHelperContract.address as Address,
      abi: VehicleHelperContract.abi,
      functionName: 'mintNFT',
      args:[BigInt(str)],
    })


Facing the same issue, did you find an answer?

It is really hard to remember the exact issue. But the problem was within the smart contract code in my case. So you can try your luck there. @gaurav
